# I am trying to update a map value in my Firestore db with a Cloud Functions trigger

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to update my map value with set function on a document but can't figure out how to update a specific map value.

In my firestore db there is a field called 'stats' and it is a map, inside of stats there is a key:value (likes_count: total), I want to update the total value for likes_count on my document, looks something like this:

stats: {
   likes_count: 8
}

I want to update that value in the map with a cloud function trigger.

With regular fields I can easily set the value but not sure how to update a specific value in a map but here is my code for the function:

```
exports.userReceivedLikeTrigger = functions.firestore
.document(ENVIRONMENT_PATH + 'user_likes/{userLikeId}')
.onCreate((change, context) => {

    const data = change.data();
    return database.doc(ENVIRONMENT_PATH + "users/" + data.postOwnerRef)
        .get()
        .then(snapshot => {
            if (snapshot.exists) {
                let count = snapshot.data().stats.receivedLikes;
                if (!count) {
                    count = 0;
                }

                // Then return a promise of a set operation to update the count
                return database.doc(snapshot.ref.path).set({
                    // BREAKS HERE with stats.likesCount
                    stats.likesCount: count + 1
                }, , {merge: true});
            } else {
                console.log("User is null");
                return null
            }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the error log?
Its a theory but with `.set()` its trying to make a new document (idk how `merge:true` works on this), but it can't make a value for `stats.likesCount` if there is no field `stats` already.
You can try to change `.set()` to `.update()` operation, it will do.

But its also not recommended to increment value with such a way. You better use

```
return db.doc(${path}).update({
  stats.likesCount: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
});
```

Because if there are multiple functions triggered, it can fail easily write incorrent data in likesCount field, but `FieldValue.increment(1)` works as a transaction so its safe to use in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I updated the code to use increment but the issue is stats.likesCount shows error in the ide so it won't compile/run. And when I do 

database.doc(snapshot.ref.path).update({
                        stats: {likescount: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)}
                    });
It overrides stats and now only has one item in the map and erases the other stats I was tracking

Comment: Try to use 'stats.likesCount' not 'stats: {likesCount : value}'. Because the first tries to update only one field, but the second updates the whole map with a new one.